# accessing cocos2d children

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

so i have code like this

```
CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", SomeString] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:25];
[SomeClassVar addChild:label];
```

Then i want to try to access it later on by -

```
[((SomeClass*)SomeTempClassVar).label color] = ccc3(255-pIntVal*150 ,255-pIntVal*55,255-pIntVal*50);
```

but i know that's not right as  SomeClass doesn't have a label as part of it's class, rather it's a child... any help? thanks

Comment: and why not to keep a pointer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use tags. It works well in iterators and you can start at like 100 for some objects and have anything below that be a specific static object you might want to refer to. You could even use #define to do something like `#define kMySprite 1`.

```
[SomeClassVar addChild:label z:0 tag:1];
```

And later access it with:

```
[YourScene getChildByTag:1];
```

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a865a57d2fe81b5afa91a984f8cd3e986

Comment: This will work for now. But i think i need to define something a little more custom in the future. Thanks.